# how to create Definition via REST API with Send Classification of type = Commercial?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, send-definition

I am trying to use an existing send classification and use it for the creation of a Send definition.

But getting the following error:

```
{
"message": "MCMS_UTM_Validation_InvalidValue_classification_IncorrectType: Classification must have type of transactional",
"errorcode": 10000,
"documentation": ""
}
```

How do I create a Definition via REST API with Send Classification of type Commercial?

Comment: Can you please post endpoint and body of your request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this documentation, you can see the existing types in the sample code. I would try "Marketing" as the type.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_send_classification.htm